# Stripe success_url format in a rails app not creating correct URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have an app that uses Stripe Checkout and creates a Stripe session and then redirects to checkout.
In my controller, this code works fine:

```
session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      subscription_data: {
        items:             [{ plan: stripe_plan }],
      },
      customer:            stripe_customer_id,
      customer_email:      stripe_customer_email,
      client_reference_id: current_user.id,
      success_url:         "http://localhost:3000/welcome_new_subscriber?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
      cancel_url:          "http://localhost:3000/charges/new?stripe_plan=" + stripe_plan,
    )
```

And correctly redirects to the URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/welcome_new_subscriber?session_id=cs_test_abcd1234
```

When I change the success_url line to the following (as advised on a few websites) it does not work:

```
      success_url:         welcome_new_subscriber_url(:session_id => '{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}'),
```

The URL resolves to:

```
http://localhost:3000/welcome_new_subscriber?session_id=%7BCHECKOUT_SESSION_ID%7D
```

It seems the {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} is not resolving correctly.
Any idea what I am doing incorrectly - I've tried every syntax change I can think of?

Comment: Can you try hard coding the URL as `"http://localhost:3000/welcome_new_subscriber?session_id={7BCHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}"` as a test? I think what's happening is that using the url builder function, it's URI-escaping the string, and therefore it can't properly evaluate the template variable

Comment: When I use:         success_url:  "http://localhost:3000/welcome_new_subscriber?session_id={7BCHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",       I get a URL of       "http://localhost:3000/welcome_new_subscriber?session_id={7BCHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}"

Comment: Sorry I meant to remove the 7B try without that

Comment: But that's what I described in my original test - see above - it works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use

```
welcome_new_subscriber_url(:session_id => '{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}')
```

Rails is trying to be helpful by URI-escaping `{` and `}`. However the Stripe gem using these as special characters to know where to replace template variables.

So you could just use

```
welcome_new_subscriber_url + "?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}"
```

Not the most elegant thing, but then again Stripe's system here is kinda wierd (why don't they let you just pass `CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID` yourself?), so we gotta make do

Comment: Perfect! So simple in the end - thanks so much. (I won't tell you how many syntax combinations I tried!)